# Eclipse: Getting null display

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, emf, acceleo

I am trying to pop up a dialog (i.e. a FileDialog) in an Eclipse Plugin, actually before of an Acceleo transformation I am running through the related UI Launcher project (http://lowcoupling.com/post/51877317162/the-acceleo-ui-launcher-project)

I am trying to do this in the related doGenerate method...

```
public void doGenerate(IProgressMonitor monitor) throws IOException {

    Display display = Display.getCurrent();
    System.out.println(display);
    //....
```

but the display I get is null
How should I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation of [`IWorkbench#getDisplay()`](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/IWorkbench.html#getDisplay%28%29) states:

> Code should always ask the workbench for the display rather than rely on `Display.getDefault()`.

So use:

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDisplay()
```

instead.

Comment: Note that this can't be used in a 'pure' e4 application where `PlatformUI` can't be used. For `syncExec` and `asyncExec` use `org.eclipse.e4.ui.di.UISynchronize` which can be injected.

Comment: @greg-449 Good to know. Haven't used e4 yet.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you looked at this yet, but in the documentation for the class [`Display`](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display.html), it says that `Display.getCurrent()` returns

> `null` if the currently running thread is not a user-interface thread for any display.

This might be the problem, but without more information I can't tell.

Comment: yes this is the problem but I still can't see where to show the dialog

Answer (score 1):

You can try getting the default display `Display.getDefault()` or the workbench display `PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDisplay()`

If you are not running in the UI thread, try the following:

```
Display.getDefault().syncExec(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // ... do work that updates the screen ...
    }
});
```

Comment: You are aware, that the second method you suggest states that using the first one is not recommended? ;)

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue. I used `getShell().getDisplay()` instead of `Display.getCurrent()` and it worked for me.